# How to make the outer line in group of polygon get bolder

Tags: javascript, svg

I draw a group of polygon using svg. One group consist of 5 polygons inside. I dont knnow how to make the outer line get bolder when its click like this picture [image].

Here's my code :

```
<div id="svgselect" style="width: 610px; height: 230px;">
      <!-- background-color:red -->
      <svg version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%">
        <g transform="scale(1.5)" id="gmain">

          <g id="P17" transform="translate(25,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B17"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">17</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P16" transform="translate(50,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B16"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">16</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P15" transform="translate(75,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B15"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">15</text>

          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>

  </div>
```

Big thanks

Comment: The outer line is not a single object, it's formed using most of the polygon elements so you'll have to redraw them all so the outer edge is a single object, while you're at it you can't have duplicate id elements which is invalid, fix those issues and you'll be able to select the edge and increase its stroke-width.

Comment: @Robert Longson I can't redraw it because I also use it as single object (each polygon inside)

Comment: Add another polygon or rect to overdraw the outer line only and increase the stroke width of that.

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah I already make it